# How to set criteria fetch mode using specification in spring jpa?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria

I need to implement a dynamic query and for that I'm using org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification interface.
For example:

```
 public class PlayerSpecification {

   public static Specification<Player> name(String name{
        return (root, criteraQuery, criteriaBuilder)-> 
            criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("name"), name);
    }

    public static Specification<Player> teamName (String teamName){
        return (root, criteraQuery, criteriaBuilder)-> 
            criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("team").get("name"), teamName);
    }
}
```

I would like to set JOIN FETCH in the Criteria.
Something like:

```
criteraQuery.setFetchMode("teams", FetchMode.EAGER);
```

Anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how the entities look like, but it should be:

```
root.fetch( "teams" );
```

See Hibernate ORM [fetch example in the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria-from-fetch).

Comment: where in the code, since root is already available?

Comment: I don't know, it depends where you need it. What kind of query are you trying to write?